# Displaying other files of the same directory in a file in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a piece of software for my organisation which I recently started, and I am using the Tkinter module in Python to create my software. I have created a word processor and an online encyclopaedia for the software.

The idea is that the main program is where you can access all the applications just by the click of a button - similar to how a desktop functions. I have created the main function that will open the applications, but when you run the program, it opens the application first and then the main program where you access the application. Everything is working fine, and there are no error messages which show up when I run the program.

I've tried researching any solutions to my problem, but they don't give me anything that I can do to fix my problem. How I have structured my function for opening the applications is that I have created a function for each application and in the `Button()` function, that function for the application will be the `command`.

Here is the code for the software that I am developing:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import os
import Wordee as wordee

window = Tk()
window.title("Brainwave One")
window.iconbitmap('Brainwave-One.ico')

def get_datetime():
    timeVariable = time.strftime("%I:%M %p, %A %d %B %Y")
    date_time.config(text=timeVariable)
    date_time.after(200,get_datetime)

def wordee():
    print(wordee)

wordee = Button(window,text="Wordee",font=("Calibri",23),command=wordee)
wordee.place(relx=0.25,rely=0.1875,anchor="center")

date_time = Label(window,font=("Calibri",15))
date_time.grid(row=0,column=0)

title = Label(window,text="Brainwave One",font=("Calibri",40))
title.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.05,anchor="center")

title = Label(window,text="From The Brainwave Incorporation",font=("Calibri",13))
title.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.083,anchor="center")

get_datetime()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You used same name `wordee` for a function and module name.

Comment: You are also using `wordee` as a name for a button. You might want to think about using a naming scheme to avoid naming conflicts (e.g. start button names with "btn_").

Comment: I have tried the naming scheme idea, but it isn't working. Do you know another solution?